# Facebook analytics redacted

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-analytics

I am sending various events from my Unity iOS game to Facebook analytics and logging them. I can see all the events being registered properly. Till few days back I was able to see breakdown of events into sections like country, gender, region,etc. But now in place of details like how many downloads per country the breakdown is showing Redacted.
Has anyone faced this problem? What can be the cause of this?

Comment: This may be due a decrease in your user count. Gender and country information, for example, is not shown when the count is too low, as it may be possible to figure out who your users are based on that information. Of course, hard to tell without more information about your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you are saying may be right but I can see this happening with all of our other apps as well. Is there a way we can contact facebook about this and ask the somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the user count for the date range you're querying has dropped below 100 users. Demographic data is redacted below that level to protect user identity. For some reports (page likes, household income etc) the redaction level is slightly higher at 1000 users.